# Applying the `Enable-PSRemoting` cmdlet for set computers

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

PowerShell 4.0, Windows domain

From `get-help Enable-PSRemoting`:

> You need to run this command only once on each computer that will
>   receive commands.

Ok, but our company has more than 500 computers... The connecting to each computer and launching on it this cmdlet will take a lot of time. Is exist the simple way of solving of this problem?

Comment: Are they in a domain? Pretty sure there's a way to apply it through Group Policy but idk how. It doesn't hurt to run it more than once though.

Comment: Yes, they are in the Windows domain (I've added this info now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done it through the `PsExec.exe` by [Mark Russinovich](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psexec.aspx). I can get computer names from Active Directory and then launch for each of them (through the cicle) this:

```
psexec \\computerName powershell -Command "Enable-PSRemoting -Force"
```

and (if this is necessary)

```
psexec \\computerName powershell -Command "Disable-PSRemoting -Force"
```

The `psexe` can be launched with `-d` option if it are to be launched in the batch processing on the many computers.